# SpringBoot httpBasic() Security with UserDetailService

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I'm pretty new to `SpringBoot Security`, mostly about Secured REST Application. I would like to do a simple `httpBasic()` security with an auto generation of `JSESSIONID` `Bearer token` from SpringSecurity.

I manage to do that with this simple configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("guest").password("{noop}guest1234").roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/*").authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
  }

}
```

Now if I call any controller without USER and PASSWORD I obtain `Unauthorized`. If I set BASIC AUTHENTICATION (on Postman) and send a call with USER and PASSWORD I reach my controller, the Authentication object is set and a `Bearer Token` coming back.

Now I want replace `inMemoryAuthentication` with `UserDetailService` auth, to retrieve user from DB. Than I replaced my configuration as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
}
```

My userDetailService is as follows:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findFirstByUsername(username);

    if (applicationUser == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }

    return applicationUser;
}
```

Now, when I try to call my controller with BASIC AUTH, the `loadUserByUsername` is getting called and the user is being found by the provided method, and the UserDetails is being returned successfully, but authentication is NOT.

How can I solve this?

------------------ UPDATE ----------------

Thanks Avi for your reply.

At the end I have solved changing my `UserDetailService` as follows:

```
Utente utente = userRepository.findByNome(username);
    
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")); // this is for testing purpose
    
return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(utente.getNome(), new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(utente.getPassword()), grantedAuthorities);
```

this way works.. maybe there was something wrong with my old `User`, which extended `UserDetails`.

I have many other perplexity about REST BASIC AUTH:

for example here:

```
return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(utente.getNome(), new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(utente.getPassword()), grantedAuthorities);
```

I **must** encrypt password (which is already cripted `md5 base64`), if I don't do that I receive an error

The other thing is that I cannot implement Custom Success Authentication (Standard) method

Comment: that is strange, was there any kind of error message in log ?

Comment: md5 is not an encryption, its a one way hashing algorithm. And a pretty weak one. You should NEVER use md5. Base64 is not encryption, it is encoding, which means the letters are simply changed, and can be easily decoded back to its original.

Spring security documentation has an excellent section when it comes to passwords:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage

Comment: also `JSESSIONID` is not a Baerer token, it is a session cookie.